# Rails and Kaminari pagination with certain priority per page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have complex query that I wrote partly as MySQL database view and partly as ActiveRecord logic in Rails. Each record has it's own priority from 0-4 where 4 is top priority.

I'm using Kaminari for pagination and I'm wondering if there's a way to show per page sets of records with some extra rules:

1. Show all #4 priority rows on first page
2. Take per_page number and show priority 3 with this formula: 0.3*per_page
3. Then do the same with priority 2
4. Then if all 3 steps didn't produced 100% of per_page show the rest with priority 0 and 1

How could I achieve result by using Rails. Or is it better to implement it directly in SQL?

Here is sample of my db view:

```
select *
from (
        select 
            s.id as source_id,
            'Spree::Store' as source_type, 
            (case when (s.created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND s.created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)
            then
                'new'
            else
                'old'
            end) as sub_type, 
            1 as priority, 
            s.created_at as created_at, 
            s.updated_at as updated_at, 
            null as owner_id
        from spree_stores as s
        where s.image_id is not NULL and s.is_hidden = false

    union 

    select 
        e.id as source_id, 
        'Event' as source_type, 
        (case 
        when (e.status = 1 and e.is_featured is false)
        then
            'live'
        when (e.is_featured = true)
        then
            'featured'
        else
            case when (e.created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND e.created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)
            then
                'new'
            else
                'old'
            end
        end) as sub_type, 
        (case 
        when (e.status = 1 or e.is_featured is true)
        then
            3
        else
            1
        end) as priority, 
        e.created_at as created_at, 
        e.updated_at as updated_at, 
        null as owner_id
    from events as e
    where e.status >= 1 and e.expires_at >= curdate()

    union 
    select 
        o.id as source_id, 
        'Spree::Order' as source_type, 
        (case when (o.created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND o.created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)
        then
            'new'
        else
            'old'
        end) as sub_type,
        1 as priority, 
        o.created_at as created_at, 
        o.updated_at as updated_at, 
        o.user_id as owner_id
    from spree_orders as o
    where o.user_id is not NULL and o.share is true and o.state = 'complete' and o.completed_at is not NULL
    union
    select 
        p.id as source_id, 
        'Spree::Product' as source_type, 
        (case when (p.created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND p.created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)
        then
            'new'
        else
            'old'
        end) as sub_type, 
        1 as priority, 
        p.created_at as created_at, 
        p.updated_at as updated_at, 
        null as owner_id
    from spree_products as p
    join spree_variants as sv on (sv.product_id = p.id and sv.is_master = true)
    join spree_assets as sa on (sa.viewable_id = sv.id and sa.viewable_type = 'Spree::Variant')
    where p.deleted_at is NULL
    group by p.id
  ) a
  order by priority desc, created_at desc;
```

This is the result I'm getting (only few lines not all 200 results): 
[image: mysql view result]

Comment: "with this formula: 0.3*per_page" what does that mean?

Comment: Hey, that means I want 30% of let's say 25 rows to be with priority #3

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what you're expecting, e.g. you seem to be implying a different number of results on each page. If it's really necessary to do it this way, you should probably provide an example with input (ie the database) and the expected output.

Comment: I updated the the description with some code and print screen from result. Let's say this: I set 25 items/rows per page. Within these 25 results I want all #4 priority rows, then 8 rows/items with priority 3 (30% from 25) and 8 with priority 2 and then the rest that's missing to complete 25 should be with priority 1.Sorry if I wasn't enough clear

Comment: This is way beyond anything Kaminari can handle itself. Kaminari needs a single query for all results, so the only solution would be if you can come up with a tricky SQL query to get the data in the exact sequence you're looking for, probably using `group` and `count`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like more complex logic than Kaminari is built for and probably worth doing it yourself. Kaminari is certainly convenient for knocking out a quick pagination UI, but it really doesn't add a huge amount of value compared to rolling your own solution. You might be able to hack it to fit your needs, but that's probably more headache than just doing it yourself.

I'm also a little skeptical the complex algorithm you're wanting is really going to benefit users. Only you know that for sure, but you might want to consider a simple "score" or "rank" column and then just use Kaminari with a query sorted by score desc.